# Air dehydrating ambient air temperature?

Tags: temperature, dehydrating

I would like to dehydrate fruits with an outdoor air drying rack in an arid climate:

[image: air drying rack]

What ambient air temperature is ideal for this? I've heard anything below 118°F is good for dehydrating. Is 100°F better or worse than, say, 80°F?

Comment: The ambient humidity will make a huge difference. In fact you almost need a desert for this to work

Comment: @ChrisH I'm assuming 0% humidity.

Comment: @Geremia I doubt you will find that, unless you are living in the middle of a desert, in a nonclimatized building. Optimal humidity for human beings is 40 to 60% relative (although many live in a wider range), but I am pretty sure that the absolute also matters for dehydrating, and so the physics get quite complicated.

Comment: @rumtscho Well, even in deserts in the U.S., the humidity rarely gets lower than ~10%.

Comment: If you know that humidity rarely gets lower than 10%, why are you assuming 0% humidity?

Comment: @Catija ∵ 0% < 50%.